# WiFi issues: Intel Wireless 7265

Tags: wireless, intel

Hey Everyone I just dual booted onto a Windows 10 computer and everything is working smoothly except the wireless card. It shows up in the menu as "device not ready." Any advice here would be helpful.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
     Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
     Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

iw dev

phy#0
         Interface wlp8s0
            ifindex 3
            wdev 0x1
            addr 34:02:86:47:bf:d0
            type managed

rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

dmesg | grep iwl
[   11.795690] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.795768] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.880785] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   12.056840] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   12.057169] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   12.057608] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   12.187700] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   13.762328] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[   38.011587] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   38.012517] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   38.073930] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   38.074377] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   82.577596] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   82.578197] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   82.639526] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   82.639969] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   91.467371] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   91.468070] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   91.529229] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   91.529673] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  358.616338] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  358.616784] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  358.678345] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  358.678790] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  615.349564] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  615.350264] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  615.411366] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  615.411812] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  618.161826] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  618.162381] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  618.223879] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  618.224423] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

Comment: Please open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and execute `lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2` and add the output to your post. Further add the output of `iw dev`.

Comment: Also add: `rfkill list all` and also: `demsg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Wi-Fi is blocked by "acer-wireless"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/895671/my-wi-fi-is-blocked-by-acer-wireless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: This also fixed my problems on AC 3165, but what was the problem? I had wondered why this Acer device was listed although I don't have such a device, but how was it interfering? Also, I guess this is a bug which should be reported, but I don't know where (running Debian).

Comment: This is a problem with the `acer_wmi` platform kernel driver. Sometimes it is loaded when it should not, or it treats the block in a wrong way. It is difficult to fix it for all laptop models. I've been fixing it the kernel, but now I almost gave up. The issue is not related to Intel adapters.