# My Wi-Fi is blocked by "acer-wireless"

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, wireless, windows

I use a Asus laptop with dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 8.1

Wifi is on but I am not able to detect Wifi networks.

When I run :

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

This is what happens:

[image: Terminal with result]

I get

```
acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You forgot about `rfkill list`

Comment: I'm sorry. I did add that now

Comment: @Pilot6 what should i do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot. That will remove the module that blocks your Wi-Fi.