# Wifi very slow on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, internet

I have the problem that while ethernet connections work just fine, whenever I connect to my home internet via wifi the connection is much slower than on any other device. While I get about 35Mbps down on a windows desktop PC, a macbook and a tablet, I only get about 2-3Mbps on my Ubunutu laptop. I tried a few fixes (disabling power management, disabling N mode, setting country code) as suggested in other threads, nothing worked for me.

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Chillroom"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 00:22:CF:DD:07:DC   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:46   Missed beacon:0
```

lshw:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 03
       serial: 1c:39:47:96:6e:ee
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:47 memory:c1200000-c121ffff memory:c123d000-c123dfff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 48
       serial: 64:80:99:89:24:7a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-71-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.2.112 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:51 memory:c1100000-c1101fff
```

uname -a:

```
Linux tim-travelmate-p645-s 4.4.0-71-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 24 12:59:01 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    5.271105] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.273376] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.300553] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.348721] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x184
[    5.348792] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.348965] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.412995] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.444120] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    7.549660] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.549856] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.607466] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.607651] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5585.892257] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5585.892457] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5585.950226] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5585.950416] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5870.008472] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5870.008657] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5870.066554] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5870.066740] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

If you need to know anything else, just let me know.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/864086/wifi-issues-intel-wireless-7265

Comment: Tried the fix suggested in it, unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `uname -a` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Output has been added.

Comment: Your post indicates that you have firmware v.17.352738.0 It's possible the newer firmware 25.30.14.0 found [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) might help This appears to have been released for kernel 4.2 but It may work for your kernel as well. Check the readme for important info.

Comment: I be honest, I am not experienced enough with Ubuntu (especially kernel stuff) to do this. The README doesn't give me enough instructions, I am simply personally unable to install this to try it out. Thank you regardless :)

Comment: @ElderGeek: ping to draw your attention to the above reaction to your post.

Comment: Could you [edit] the output of `dmesg | grep iwl` into your post? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Related to [Intel 7265 support](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#and_7265_support)

Comment: Output has been added.

Comment: If @chili555 solution didn't work for you, try debugging as described and report bugs as necessary as described [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/debugging)

Answer (score 1):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Finally, Network Manager will default to ethernet if it's available. Please make your tests with the ethernet detached.

By the way, I believe the -17 firmware is the latest suitable firmware. Extracting the file that @Elder Geek referenced yields the older -14 firmware.

Comment: Hi man, I already saw your answer on another post and did all the steps, unfortunately that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If [@Chili555 answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/903721/225694) doesn't work for you, you may simply be suffering from RF interference, AKA Platform noise. This is common in the 2.4GHz band. Here's a quote from https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

**About platform noise:**

```
Wi-Fi heavily relies on radio frequencies, and those are subject to
interference. Interference may come from another Wi-Fi device, or from many 
other non Wi-Fi devices (e.g. microwaves) that operates on the same frequency,
and it might also come from other components of your own device/computer – 
this is known as 'platform noise'. Platform noise depends on the actual
platform/computer and its design/manufacturing, and not on the Intel Wi-Fi 
module.

Some common sources of platform noise might be:

    The PCIe bus, especially when switching in/out of power saving modes.
    USB3 and graphics (in certain scenarios).
    Sometimes, even the fact that several ingredients’ ground lines are
    connected can cause noise.

This kind of interference might happen on 2.4GHz band, it is much less likely 
to happen on 5.2GHz band. Also note that using 40MHz (and not 20MHz) channel 
 bandwidth will increase the probability to suffer from platform noise 
(since more frequencies might impact the Wi-Fi performance).

Some potential work-around options to this issue:

    Disable Wi-Fi's power save (prevent the PCIe link to go to power save): 
    power_scheme=1 module parameter for iwlmvm
    Disable USB3 in BIOS (if possible), it not, just stop using it
    Disable 40MHz on 2.4GHz: cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz module parameter
    Use 5GHz band (on devices that support 5GHz operation)

The fact that one of these options helped doesn't prove that the issue being 
troubleshooted is 'platform noise', but it may be an indication.

Another thing that can be tried is to modify the antenna position. The antennas 
are typically located in the lid of the laptop. It is worth trying to
open / close the lid or to rotate the system and see if it has any effect.
```